# How to find the average of a certain key from a file in comma-separated format in Python?

Tags: python

So how could I find the average from the file. I am new at python.

My file looks like this:

```
dog,3
dog,11
cat,3
cat,4
cat,15
```

How could I make the code find the average of "cat"?

This is not full code:

```
def quiztime():
    score = 0
    k_file=open('k_form.txt','a')
    l_file=open('l_form.txt','a')
    e_file=open('e_form.txt','a')
    print('PLEASE TYPE NUMBERS ONLY!!!')
    print('Welcome to this quiz :)\n')
    name=input('What is your name \n')
    print('Welcome ',name,'\n')
    form=input("What form are you K - E - L")
    for i in range(10):  #Asking 10 Questions.
        correct = Question()            
        if correct:
            score += 1
            print('Correct!\n')
        else:
            print('Incorrect!\n')
    print ('Your score was {}/10'.format(score))
    if form=='K':
        k_file.writelines(str(name)+','+str(score) +'\n')
        k_file.close()
    if form=='E':
        e_file.writelines(str(name)+','+str(score) +'\n')
        e_file.close()
    if form=='L':
        l_file.writelines(str(name)+','+str(score) +'\n')
        l_file.close()
    master = Tk()
    w = Label(master, text="", fg="green", bg="black", font=("Helvetica", 12)).pack()

    print('To view the data in files please type the password\n')
    passw=input('Type The Password\n')

    kf_file=open('k_form.txt','r')
    lf_file=open('l_form.txt','r')
    ef_file=open('e_form.txt','r')

    if passw=='teacher':
        print("Type A Form e.g E, K ,L")     
        tform=input('=')
        if tform=='E':
            print('Type In *alphabetical* To Get Alphabetical order.')
            print('Type In *highest score* To Get Highest score.')
            print('Type In *average score* To Get average score.')
            order=input('Type= ')

            if order=='alphabetical':
                with open('e_form.txt', 'r') as r:
                    for line in sorted(r):
                        print(line, end='')

            if order=='highest score':
                scores = []
                with open('e_form.txt','r') as f:
                    for line in f:
                        name, score = line.split(',', 1)
                        score = int(score)
                        scores.append((name, score))
                scores.sort(key=lambda s: s[1])
                scores.reverse()

                for name, score in scores:
                    print(name, score)

            if order=='average score':
                data = []
                with open('file.txt', 'r') as a:
                    for line in a:
                        field = line.split(',', 1)
                        field = int(field)
                        rowdata = map(float, field)
                        data.extend(rowdata)
                print(sum(data)/len(data))
```

Comment: So what problems do you have with your code?

Comment: It is best to have proper formatting of the question, so that more people are willing to look at your issue. I improved your formatting. If you share code, then you need to describe how it currently behaves in contrast to how you want it to behave.

Answer (score 0):

First, move the code that calculates `scores` to before the `if order=='alphabetical':` line, so that it's calculated by default and available in the rest of the function.

Now you can do the following:

```
cat_list = [i[1] for i in scores if i[0]=='cat']
print(sum(cat_list)/len(cat_list))
```

This parses a `scores` of `[('cat', 3), ('dog', 4), ('cat', 2)]` to print an average of `2.5`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a dictionary of lists.

```
def get_dictionary():
    handle = open("file_with_cats_n_dogs", "rb")
    d = {}
    for line in handle:
        key, number = line.strip().split(",")
        if key in d:
            d[key] += [float(number)]
        else:
            d[key] = [float(number)]
    return d
```

Then you can do:

```
def get_avg(numbers_dict, key):
    avg = sum(numbers_dict[key])/len(numbers_dict[key])
    return avg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function as shown below and use it to find out average for items like dog,cat etc...

```
import csv

ef_file = open('e_form.txt')


def avg(fileHnadler,avgFor):
   csv_rows = csv.reader(fileHnadler)
   count=total=0
   for row in csv_rows:
       if row[0]==avgFor:
            total += float(row[1])
            count += 1

   if count!=0:
       return total/count
   else:
       return 'No Data in File'
```

Then you can call function as shown below

```
cat_avg = avg(ef_file,'cat')
```

In your case,as you are anyway opening file in your code. So you just have call this function with proper arguments/parameters to get required average value....

Answer (score 0):

Using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) a list containing the values for each key can be constructed. [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) simplifies processing of the data from the file, splitting it into separate fields and stripping new lines characters. Then the average for each key can be calculated by iterating over the items in the dictionary, summing each list and dividing by the list length. Here is the code:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

with open('file.txt') as f:
    pets = defaultdict(list)
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        pets[row[0]].append(float(row[1]))

    for pet, values in pets.items():
        print('{}: {:.2f}'.format(pet, sum(values) / len(values)))
```

**Output**

```
dog: 7.00
cat: 7.33
```